# Adding keydown events alongside click listeners - which key events to listen to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I am trying to add more accessibility to my app so i've added `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` to my eslint process. This has been great, however I have a question in regards to the `click-events-have-key-events` rule (https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/click-events-have-key-events.md ).

I want to add an `onKeyDown` or an `onKeyPress` anywhere I'm using the `onClick` in my react code. However I am not sure which keycode I should be listening to.

If, for example, I just do

```
  <div
     onClick={this.myFunction}
     onKeyDown={this.myFunction}
     />
```

That onKeyDown function fires when i just tab away from that div. So I am thinking I need to filter keyCodes, however when trying to meed accessibility standards, I'm not sure *which* keyCodes I need to listen for. Is the enter keyCodes enough - do all screen readers respect this for example?

Looking for some insight into this to help make my app more accessible and screen reader friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't ask specifically about this but the best solution is to use a native html element if possible.  See the [first rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1).  Native elements have the behavior built in to the element and work great with screen readers.

However, sometimes you need to create a custom element and that's where [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/) comes in.  But you need both [attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#x6-6-definitions-of-states-and-properties-all-aria-attributes) and a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) to make a custom element, and additionally you need keyboard/mouse handlers if the element will be interactive.

The types of keyboard events you listen for depends on the [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions).  For example, if you were creating your own [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#link) element, instead of using an <a>, you'd listen for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.  If you were creating your own [button](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#button), you'd listen for **both** the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> keys.

The types of keys you listen for are explained in the design patterns in "[WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#aria_ex)".  For example, see the "[Keyboard Interaction](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-3)" section for buttons.